# How to scraping data using Simple HTML DOM Library and the target is ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

The url I want to scrape is https://www.tokopedia.com/juraganlim/info

and I just want to get the number of transaction like in this image (inside box is what I need to take):

[image]

I really am confused with ajax because I don't know the url which comes or goes.
When I inspect using Firefox it produces so many links.

Please anyone can give me a clue? Or directly the script?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your original question and add your code so that we can see what youre doing wrong.

Comment: @ahmaddarul, seems to me you first need to make log in. Does 
**simple-html-dom** provide it? 
You also need to navigate to the target page and inspect its requests with web dev. tools. Filter requests with `xhr` tag (second after `all` tag). http://joxi.ru/KAx7GZwUOlvY28